# What is "exit" in Solaris?

Tags: unix, solaris, exit, built-in

This feels like a newbie question, but I've been working with Solaris for years, and am stumped by this.

Does anyone know what happens when I type exit on a Solaris command line?

I'm using Solaris 10, and I'd like to know what happens when I run "exit".

I assumed it was a command, but I can't find it:

```
$ uname -a
SunOS base 5.10 Generic_150400-05 sun4v sparc sun4v
$ which exit
no exit in /usr/bin . /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/ucb /usr/X/bin /sbin /usr/sbin /usr/local/sbin /usr/sbin /usr/sbin /usr/local/bin
$ sudo find / -name exit
$
```

Thanks,
Warwick.

Comment: The process ends itself? I'd imagine that internally, the shell is calling `exit(0)` after it does some cleanup.

Comment: It terminates the shell, so in many cases it will get you back to the login prompt, or close your window.  It's a function/command that's built into the shell executable.

Comment: `exit` is a *shell built-in command*, like `cd`, and not an executable file which is why it can't be found. See `man sh` (or as suitable for the shell).

Comment: @user2864740: Surprisingly, there's also a `/usr/bin/cd` command on Solaris, perhaps useful for detecting whether you have permission to `cd` to a directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`exit` is a shell built-in.  Think about how a shell typically works without built-ins.  It executes a file that is in the command path by forking a new process.  Exit terminates the current process.  If there was an external `exit` program, calling it would just exit the `exit` program.

Therefore, `exit` is one of the built-in commands that bash itself (and other shells) knows how to interpret (along with `cd`).  It simply does an `exit` within the process itself.

Excellent explanation on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin

Comment: Thanks very much. That is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: An alternative to `which` which identifies builtins, functions and aliases as well as executable files is `type`.  `type exit` returns `exit is a shell builtin`.